# Cambiar color de resaltado en items de MenuStrip

Tags: c#, menú

estoy trabajando con C# en el cual voy a desarrollar una aplicación que contenga un menú el cual pueda ser dinámico. Opte por trabajar con MenuStrip, es la primera vez que lo hago.

Quiero hacer mi barra de menú color negra con la fuente en blanco. Lo duda que me es como puedo cambiar el color de fondo y de las letras al pasar el ratón encima.

En la siguiente foto se puede ver que al pasarlo por encima tiene un color azul el cual no resalta y no deja ver el texto de una forma comoda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Igualmente al presionarlo se ve en un tono blanco que completamente se pierde de vista el texto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pudiera ajustar estos valores de colores tanto del fondo como de la letra al pasarlo por encima con el mouse y al momento de dar clic de este MenuTrip.

O si alguien pudiera darme otra opción de crear un menú dentro de C# se lo agradecería bastante.

Gracias de antemano, saludos, buena tarde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lo que necesitas es cambiar el [renderizador](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) de tu menú.

Primero importa el espacio de nombre `Drawing`.

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Agrega este código en el constructor de tu formulario.
Sustituye `NombreMenu` por el nombre de tu menú, la mayoría de las veces es `menuStrip1`.

```
    public RelojKarosso()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NombreMenu.Renderer = new MiRenderizador();
    }
```

Y agrega esta clase privada.

```
    private class MiRenderizador: ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Item.Selected) base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
            else
            {
                Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, rc); //Elige el color que desees
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 1, 0, rc.Width - 2, rc.Height - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¡Excelente amigo, un saludo y muchas gracias!